# ARM Template - integrate azure functions and logic apps with VSO repo

Tags: git, azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps

I'm developing an ARM template where I want to deploy logic app, which uses azure functions which should be up to date all the time with my external repo (VSO) (using Microsoft.Web/sites/sourcecontrols).

my `deployment.json` looks like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "parameters": {
    "repoUrl": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "https://{USER}:{TOKEN}@{GIT_URL}"
    },
    "environment": {
    "type":"string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "branch": "[concat('master-', parameters('environment'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "name": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "kind": "functionapp",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
      ],
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "name": "web",
          "type": "sourcecontrols",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('functionAppName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "RepoUrl": "[parameters('repoURL')]",
            "branch": "[variables('branch')]",
            "IsManualIntegration": true,
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "appSettings": [
            //AzureWebJobsDashboard, AzureWebJobsStorage, and so on          
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('logicAppName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', variables('servicebusConnectionName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/sourcecontrols', variables('functionAppName'), 'web')]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "order-create"
      },
      //(...)
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see I have: `"IsManualIntegration": true`. In resources.azure.com everything looks with expected values:

```
"properties": {
  "repoUrl": "https://{GIT_REPO_URL}",
  "branch": "master-dev",
  "isManualIntegration": true,
  "deploymentRollbackEnabled": false,
  "isMercurial": false,
  "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
}
```

In this case, everything works well. When I click "Edit" button, change the value to `false`, save changes by button "PUT", like below:

[image]

Then appears a loader, after few seconds my changes are discarded and still "isManualIntegration" is set to "true".

I have tried also a second approach, to push template with "isManualIntegration": "false"/false (both approaches) and I see conflicts in logic app builds (view from logic app build):
[image]

When i go to my azure functions. Then the function is created (which i expected), but there's no "methods" inside. All app settings are created.

Do you know how to solve the problem? Do i need to attach next resource in my template?

**EDIT:**
I have got in my resource manager that properties after deploying with `IsManualIntegration: false`:

```
"provisioningDetails": "Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.OAuthException: Vso TestWebHook: Failed because you are not an administrator on the VSTS project.  Access Denied: MY_INITIALS needs the following permission(s) on the resource PublisherSecurity to perform this action: Edit Subscription
```

at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.VsoProxy.(...)"

Current problem: How to add `edit subscription` action for me if **I'm** administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Setting-up-a-VSTS-account-so-it-can-deploy-to-a-Web-App) may be the step that is missing - but I only thought that was required if you weren't manually providing a {user}:{token}.  Let me know.  I also believe you do the steps linked above you no longer have to specify a user and token - the Function deployment will automatically securely grab the code which helps keep your ARM template a little simpler.

Comment: thanks for the answer, all is done for all steps which you described

Comment: I have not checked it yet - on monday i will check all things :)

Comment: I would start by first deploying all manually and setting up continuous integration in settings and see if that works. Will help narrow issue

Comment: OK. I'll investigate some time to find the problem. I've got a tip from one guy to configure new endpoint in VSO project, like to add new Azure Resource Manager endpoint service (Settings -> services -> endpoints -> new endpoint -> Add Azure Resource Manager Service Endpoint). Do you think it may help? (I dont have access to do that, but maybe now you could say - its the problem / it doesnt matter)